# Chemfig: \chemmove proper anchor

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

How can I do so that the arrow drawn through the `\chemmmove` command does not overlay with the `C-R''`' bond?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\definecolor{cerulean}{HTML}{0080C0}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \schemestart
    \chemfig[]{\chemabove{R}{\scriptstyle\color{magenta}{\delta +}}(-[:0]@{Nu}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\color{cerulean}{\delta -}}H)}
    \+
    \chemfig[]{
    R'(-[:0]@{El}\chemabove[0.5pt]{C}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3.5mm}\color{magenta}{\delta +}}(-[0]H)(-[2]R'')(-[6]\chembelow{Cl}{\scriptstyle\color{cerulean}{\delta -}}))
    }
    \arrow(.base east--.base west){->[][][3pt]}   
   \chemname{\chemfig{R'-CH_{2}(-[:90]OR)}}{Etere}
   \+
   \chemfig{HCl}
  \schemestop
  \chemnameinit{}
  \chemmove[yshift=25em]{\draw[shorten <=7pt, shorten >=7pt](Nu).. controls +(north:1cm) and +(north:1cm).. (El);}
\end{figure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=100764#p100764)

Comment: Does `(Nu).. controls +(north:1cm) and +(105:1cm).. (El)` for example achieve an effect that you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer)

You can just exploit the syntax of the `..controls..` 'command' (if I may call it that), like so:

```
\chemmove[...]{\draw[...](Nu).. controls +(north:1cm) and +(105:1cm).. (El);}
```

The `105` simply means 105 degrees measured counterclockwise from the positive 'x' axis, instead of `north`, which basically means `90`. You may change this to whatever angle you fancy.

**Full code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\definecolor{cerulean}{HTML}{0080C0}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \schemestart
    \chemfig[]{\chemabove{R}{\scriptstyle\color{magenta}{\delta +}}(-[:0]@{Nu}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\color{cerulean}{\delta -}}H)}
    \+
    \chemfig[]{
    R'(-[:0]@{El}\chemabove[0.5pt]{C}{\scriptstyle\hspace{3.5mm}\color{magenta}{\delta +}}(-[0]H)(-[2]R'')(-[6]\chembelow{Cl}{\scriptstyle\color{cerulean}{\delta -}}))
    }
    \arrow(.base east--.base west){->[][][3pt]}   
   \chemname{\chemfig{R'-CH_{2}(-[:90]OR)}}{Etere}
   \+
   \chemfig{HCl}
  \schemestop
  \chemnameinit{}
  \chemmove[yshift=25em]{\draw[shorten <=7pt, shorten >=7pt](Nu).. controls +(north:1cm) and +(105:1cm).. (El);}
\end{figure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image: controls..]